# MySQL: Count occurrences of values

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to be able to get data showing how many of which room types does every hotel have.
Something like this:

```
HotelName  RoomName               NumOfRooms
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Hotel 1    Queen Guest Room       23
Hotel 1    Queen Guest Room Plus  17
(7+ RoomNames for Hotel 1)
...
Hotel 2    Queen Guest Room       14
Hotel 2    Queen Guest Room Plus  9
(7+ RoomNames for Hotel 2)
...
Hotel 3    Queen Guest Room       9
Hotel 3    Queen Guest Room Plus  6
(7+ RoomNames for Hotel 3)
```

I've only gotten so far as this:

```
SELECT `Hotel`.HotelName, `RoomType`.RoomName FROM `Hotel`
RIGHT JOIN `Room` ON `Hotel`.HotelID = `Room`.HotelID
RIGHT JOIN `RoomType` ON `Room`.TypeID = `RoomType`.TypeID
GROUP BY `RoomID` ORDER BY `RoomID` ASC;
```

It only results in showing where every room is located and what type it is, I just can't figure out how to use that, I believe I should be using nested queries but I'm not sure how to do that.

**Setup**

I've got a hotel database, there are three hotels, each hotel has rooms and every room is one of nine types (guest room, guest room plus, single guest room, etc...)

Hotel:

```
HotelID  HotelName
------------------
1        Hotel 1
2        Hotel 2
3        Hotel 3
```

RoomType:

```
TypeID  RoomName               
-----------------------------
1       Queen Guest Room       
2       Queen Guest Room Plus  
3       Single  Guest Room     

6 more...
```

Room:

```
RoomID  HotelID TypeID
----------------------
1       1       3     
2       1       3     
3       1       3     

150+ more...
```

I'd really appreciate all the help I could get thank you!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Avoid a `RIGHT JOIN` when ever possible. Use `LEFT JOIN` instead. `RIGHT JOIN` is a syntax sugar which is more harmful than useful most of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CROSS JOIN` `Hotel` and `RoomType` to get all combinations of hotels and room types. Then `LEFT JOIN` `Room` to add all rooms to a given hotel room type combination. If a hotel hasn't a room of the type `NULL` values will be added. Then use `GROUP BY` and `count()` to get the count of the room types a hotel has.

```
SELECT h.HotelName,
       rt.RoomName,
       count(r.TypeID)
       FROM Hotel h
            CROSS JOIN RoomType rt
            LEFT JOIN Room r
                      ON r.HotelID = h.HotelID
                         AND r.TypeID = rt.TypeID
       GROUP BY h.HotelName,
                h.HotelID,
                rt.RoomName,
                rt.TypeID;
```

Unless using `count(*)` `count()` will not count `NULL` values. So using `count(r.TypeID)` we get 0 when a hotel hasn't a room of the respective type.

(Note: I added `h.HotelID` and `rt.TypeId` to the `GROUP BY` because there might be more than one hotel or room type with the same name.)

Comment: Perfect, just what I was hoping for! Thank you so much, cheers!